# node(25043,0x70001394a000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffb483d5300: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I have this error:

```
node(25043,0x70001394a000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffb483d5300: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I have no clue what this means, and there is nothing online that helps me fix this. I am not sure what the issue is as it just appeared out of no where. I am using `node.js` for my app.

Comment: Malloc is dynamic memory allocation, reallocation ... Does the issue occur on specific parts of your code? Can you provide some snippets for context?

Comment: @VincentMenzel interesting okay. No, it is not happening in a specific part of my code, it just randomly started happening locally, but it is random when it happens.

Comment: By any chance do you use ibm_db package in your node project ?